# How to use Django template tags in angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I'm using Django 1.9.8 and angular 1.5.8. I have a Django template named `song.html` that has an angular component, which uses its own template. When I try to use any Django template tags like `{% csrf_token %}` inside my angular component's template (named `my-component.template.html`) it is not rendered and the exact markup tag is displayed.

```
<!-- song.html -->

{% block content %}
<head>
  ....
</head>
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <!-- some html.... -->

    <my-component></my-component> 

</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the template for `my-component`

```
<!-- my-component.template.html -->
<div id = "my_div">
   <!-- some html -->
</div>
<form action = "" method = "post>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- ....remaining form contents -->
</form>
```

Django is not creating the hidden form input and the exact `{% csrf_token %}` tag appears on my form. However, when I move the form from the angular template to the Django template, the csrf_token properly generates, but then obviously my component isn't working properly because the directive isn't in place. So basically Django will create the csrf hidden input on the Django template, but not the angular template.

How can I use Django markup inside of my angular template? I apologize if this has been asked, but I'm not quite sure how to word it.

I have created a workaround by setting a global javascript variable on `song.html` to the value of the csrf_token, manually creating a hidden form input and then using javascript to set the value of that hidden input to the token. However, I would rather learn the correct way to solve this problem.